# How do I assign a domain name to a custom domain in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-appservice

I am new to Azure or web server configuration in general, so I am not sure if I am asking the right questions. I've bought a domain in Azure and it required me to point to an App Service which I did. Now having this domain ([www.mysite.com](http://www.mysite.com)), I wanted to have subdomains.  So I added some host name bindings (abc.mysite.com and xyz.mysite.com).

Now, I want to buy and assign a domain name to abc.mysite.com like [www.myabc.com](http://www.myabc.com) so I can use this name to browse instead of abc.mysite.com. I do not know how to go about it since every time I buy a domain in Azure, it asks me to point it to an App Service.

How do I do this? Additional question, is creating hostname bindings the right way to create sudomains?

Answer (score 1):

When you create a new azure app, you have to name it like http://yourapp.azurewebsites.net/

Here, yourapp is the name I have given above while the creation of the app. Remaining name (azurewebsites.net) is common for everyone.

Now suppose you need to change the domain name to something like http://yourdomain.com, then you need to assign a custom domain name to your app as I am explaining in my blog in the following link

[How to configure an Azure App from Marketplace in a custom domain](http://cloudcompute.info/how-to-configure-an-azure-app-from-marketplace-in-a-custom-domain/)